# Why does adding Spring DI into a Jersey 1.19.1 make my resource a singleton?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, singleton, jersey-1.0

My goal in this entire endeavor is to try and inject a data source into a resource that can change at runtime. I am trying to avoid having to bloat the logic inside my resource if at all possible.

This is a legacy application with Jersey 1.19.1 using Spring 4.1.9.RELEASE (spring-aop, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-core, spring-expression, spring-web)

So here is my example resource:

```
@Path("/test)
public class TestResource {
  public TestResource(){
     System.out.println("Constructor Hit");
  }
}
```

If I run hit this resource I get the following output

```
...request...
Constructor Hit
...request...
Constructor hit
```

So, the resource is created everytime there is a request, great!

Now, I want to use spring to inject a bean into this resource, so I get the following class.

```
@Path("/test)
@Component
public class TestResource {
  @Inject
  public TestResource(MyBean test){
     System.out.println("Constructor Hit");
  }
}
```

Now I get the following output

```
Constructor hit
...request...
...request...
```

The resource is only created once (I'm guessing at Spring application creation time).

Is there a way to fix this? I believe it is because I annotate with `@Component` but I can't seem to get the injection part without that.

Comment: And why is that an issue? As long as your class doesn't hold state it can be perfectly well be a singleton.

Comment: The idea is that I want to switch out at runtime what `MyBean` instance actually is. So for instance, it is a datasource that I want to change at runtime and rather than adding logic to the resource of how to extract from a factory, I just wanted to have that instance injected into the resource to keep the logic cleaner.

Comment: Then use AOP to wrap your `MyBean` which contains the logic. You still need to implement the logic somewhere, instead of doing it manually and have creational overhead there might be smarter ways...

Comment: Was trying to avoid the proxy layer but I will investigate it further.

Comment: You still need something, be it a factory or not. Either inject the factory into yur resource and call a method to get the actual bean, if you use a factorybean you still need the logic (which would in turn be quite a contraption because for some reason you need it to differ per request not sure why).

Comment: I won't be every request that differs, its more like hey, this data source has changed and I need to flip it over without restarting the application. Also, I know I'm being pedantic over not injecting a factory and then extracting, it was that I read in the jersey-spring and jersey documents that every request is a new instance, so I was wondering if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118965/discussion-between-erik-l-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 0):

Spring's default scope is singleton. when you call prototype class in singleton, spring DI inject prototype class just once at instantiate time.
read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000406/how-many-instances-created-for-singleton-bean-referring-to-a-session-bean-protot) if you want the singleton bean get a new instance of the prototype bean at runtime.